# grep recursive + backwords + last match

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Here is what I want to achieve.

I want to search for a pattern recursively in sub-directories and return the last match in **each** file.

I tried

```
grep -r "UVM_INFO" run.*/mti.log | tail -n 1
```

But this returns only the last match in the last file it searched. However, I want the last match in every file where there is a match.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaned-up version of [user1234424's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791013/428843).

I'm not 100% sure how `grep -r` treats symlinks, so the `find` might need a bit of adjustment for that, but this should be correct otherwise.

`find run.*/mti.log -type f -print0 | while read -rd '' filename; do grep UVM_INFO "$filename"|tail -1; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
echo " " > results
for filename in find $(run.*/mti.log)
do
    grep "UVM_INFO" $filename|tail -n 1  >> results
done
```

## not sure about this search criteria for find - might need to be changed

Comment: type this solution all on one line. You might need `;` where there are currently line breaks. You may not need to store output to `>results`, just let it go to terminal window. Good luck.

Comment: The shell syntax is wrong, and even if it were right, it could still have issues if any of the directories had spaces or other unusual characters in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on [@Aaron's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792085/641955):

```
find run.*/mti.log -type f -exec sh -c 'grep UVM_INFO {} | tail -n 1' \;
```

It's shorter without the `while` loop, but it's less efficient because of spawning a new `sh` process for every file.